# Sidewiki - Google Tool bar

Tags: sidebar, google-toolbar

I have sidewiki. I make an entry on a web page. Persons who visit that web page do not subscribe to sidewiki. How will they get to know that there is a sidewiki entry and then read it? Another way to say the same question: Should the person making the sidewiki entry and the person reading it -- should both subscribe to Google sidewiki and install it on their browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Both people have to have SideWiki installed. There is no way to see SideWiki entries without the extension.

Comment: And the same goes for StumbleUpon, which is what Google Sidewiki is a copy of.